# Is this combination of one synchronous and one asynchronous process running concurrently?

Tags: javascript, concurrency, promise

Would you please tell me if the results listed at the end of this snippet mean that the promises `p5()` and `f5()` are processing concurrently?

In my project code, `sync()` builds and returns a document fragment to replace a node in the DOM but doesn't replace it, and `p5()` is an indexedDB database readwrite operation.  I don't want to replace the existing node with the new fragment unless the database operation succeeds, and I want to provide the user options based on why either `p5()` or `f5()` might have failed.

I wondered if placing the synchronous function `sync()` in a promise, so that it could be placed in a `Promise.allSettled`, would allow these two process to run concurrently and then check errors when both have settled, instead of waiting for `p5()` to complete before beginning to build the fragment in `sync()`.

I know very little about concurrency but these results appear to indicate that `sync()` or `f5()` took two seconds to complete and completed three seconds before `p5()`, and all was settled in five seconds instead of perhaps taking seven seconds total.

Thank you.

```js
function p5() { 
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( () => resolve( 'p5 resolved at : ' + new Date()), 5000 ); }); }
    
function f5() {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    try { resolve( sync() ); }
    catch(e) { reject( e ) }
    }); }
    
function sync() {
  let i, str ='';
  for( i=0; i < 50000000; i++ ) str = str + 'A string of text';
  i = str = null;
  return 'sync complete at : ' + new Date();
 }
 
 console.log( 'start : ' + new Date() );
 Promise.allSettled( [ p5(), f5() ] ).then( (r) => { console.log(r[0]); console.log(r[1]); } );
 
 /* Results:
start : Sat Feb 22 2020 00:36:53 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

r[0]:
{ "status": "fulfilled",
  "value": "p5 resolved at : Sat Feb 22 2020 00:36:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" }

r[1]: 
{ "status": "fulfilled",
  "value": "sync complete at : Sat Feb 22 2020 00:36:55 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" }
*/
```

```js
    function p5() { 
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout( () => resolve( 'p5 resolved at : ' + new Date()), 5000 ); }); }
        
    function f5() {
      return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        try { resolve( sync() ); }
        catch(e) { reject( e ) }
        }); }
        
    function sync() {
      let i, str ='';
      for( i=0; i < 50000000; i++ ) str = str + 'A string of text';
      i = str = null;
      return 'sync complete at : ' + new Date();
     }
     
     console.log( 'start : ' + new Date() );
     Promise.allSettled( [ f5(), p5() ] ).then( (r) => { console.log(r[0]); console.log(r[1]) });
     
/*     
start : Sat Feb 22 2020 01:37:08 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

{"status": "fulfilled",
  "value": "sync complete at : Sat Feb 22 2020 01:37:10 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"}

{"status": "fulfilled",
  "value": "p5 resolved at : Sat Feb 22 2020 01:37:15 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" }
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you called the actual asynchronous operation `p5()` first, it will get started and run in the background while your synchronous operation `f5()` runs.

The asynchronous `p5()` can't process its completion until the synchronous code is done because the main JS thread can only do one thing at a time and the synchronous code is blocking the event loop so no completion events from any asynchronous operations can be processed until the synchronous `f5()` is done.

If you switched the code to reorder `p5()` and `f5()` like this:

```
 Promise.allSettled( [ f5(), p5() ] ).then(...)
```

Then, there would be no concurrency because `p5()` wouldn't even get started until `f5()` was done.

> I wondered if placing the synchronous function `sync()` in a promise, so that it could be placed in a Promise.allSettled, would allow these two process to run concurrently and then check errors when both have settled, instead of waiting for p5() to complete before beginning to build the fragment in `sync()`.

---

FYI, there is no real advantage to wrapping the call to `sync()` in a promise.  You could have also just done this:

```
p5().then(...);
f5();
```

That would get you the same overall execution time until both are done because `p5()` still gets started first and gets to run in the background and again can't process its completion event until the blocking `f5()` is done.

---

Also, you should know that you don't have to wrap `sync()` in a promise.  You can pass plain values to `Promise.all()` or `Promise.allSettled()` too.  So, you could also do this:

```
Promise.allSettled([p5(), sync()]).then(...)
```

And, it would work the same.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  May I ask a follow up question please?  If you do not wrap `sync()` in a promise, and want to catch potential errors in a number of code sections within the function to indicate the location of the error, is there another way to return a custom error message other than using a `return` from within a `catch`. I ask because it appears that the `status` will always be `fulfilled` even when return an error.  Thank you.

Comment: @Gary - If `sync` can throw synchronously, then it may be helpful to wrap it in a promise so you can more easily capture it's completion as a rejected promise with the completion of `p5()`.  You are correct that if you want to catch exceptions inside of `sync()` and convert them to returned errors (instead of exceptions), then you just `return` some detectable error value (usually an `Error` object or a subclass of an `Error` object).